# AngularJs $watch monitor and update vise versa variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form on which there are 2 text inputs

1. Discount %
2. Discount Amount

**Scenario**

On `discount %` change, the `Discount Amount` should change and
On `discount amount` change, the `discount %` should change

I know the problem sounds silly but I am not able to do the task by using `$watch` as shown below in the code.

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return vm.orderDetails.discountPer;
}, function (newV, oldV) {
    vm.orderDetails.discountAmount = (newV / 100 * vm.orderDetails.totalPurcasePrice).toFixed(2);

    vm.totalOrderPrice();
});
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return vm.orderDetails.discountAmount;
}, function (newV, oldV) {
    vm.orderDetails.discountPer = (newV / vm.orderDetails.totalPurcasePrice * 100).toFixed(2);

    vm.totalOrderPrice();
});
```

However, I am able to find a bad workaround where I am monitoring text change of both inputs and by using a boolean flag `valueChanging` I am able to complete my task but I am not satisfied with it. Please suggest If you have some better solution.

Answer (score 0):

A working way would be to specify the vaiable you want to watch as a string like this:

```
$scope.$watch('vm.orderDetails.discountPer', function (newV, oldV) {
    vm.orderDetails.discountAmount = (newV / 100 * vm.orderDetails.totalPurcasePrice).toFixed(2);
    vm.totalOrderPrice();
});
$scope.$watch('vm.orderDetails.discountAmount', function (newV, oldV) {
    vm.orderDetails.discountPer = (newV / vm.orderDetails.totalPurcasePrice * 100).toFixed(2);

    vm.totalOrderPrice();
});
```

If you want to watch the complete object you could use watch as this

```
$scope.$watch('vm.orderDetails', function (newV, oldV) {
    //Update what you need...
}, true);
```

Note: the true in the end tells $watch to compare the values in the objects and not the reference

Comment: I think I should have been more clear with my problem. **1** i need to be specific what user has changed `per` or `amount`. if user have changed the `amount` then `per` should be updated and so with the `amount`. I have to watch them separately. Even if monitor single object, when I will change its value then `watch` will be fired again

Comment: @VikasBansal OK, is the active user stored somewhere? sounds like you should separete presentation logic from business logic. watch the values the user enters and send that value to a service/function which is independent of the value you are watching.

Comment: Then how will i bind the ng-model. Can you create a small fiddle

Comment: @VikasBansal You bind it the same way. just store the actual calculation result in another model then the vm. If you create a fiddle with this current situation I will try and solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Usually data changes for 2 reasons: user action and rest calls. In second case you just need correct callback, when in first case you should use `ng-change`.

Using `$watch('A', onChangeA)` seems to be OK, but in fact you are loosing control over your application:

- first watch run every digest cycle, even if user changed something in the other part of page.
- second when `onChangeA` runs, you do not know why `A` changed - cause of user input, cause of your calculations or cause of something else (i.e. floating point error)

Comment: I will have to use a **flag** e.g *valueChanging*, right?

Comment: It's not writing as well :(